# Finding the cheapest price of a combination of 2 models with a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following Models:

```
class Rim < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :wheels

    scope :cheapest, -> { minimum(:price) }
end

class Tyre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :wheels

    scope :cheapest, -> { minimum(:price) }
end

class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :rim
    belongs_to :tyre
end
```

Basically every rim and tyre have a price, and when you put 2 together, the price is the combination of both prices, **but not all rims and tyres cam combine**, so I can't simple search for the cheapest of `Rim` and `Tyre` and put them together. I have to actually go through all the entries listed on the table `wheels`.

How could I create a scope on `Wheel` to get the cheapest wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method that computes it:

```
class Wheel < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :rim
  belongs_to :tyre 
  def self.cheapest
    all.min_by{|wheel| wheel.rim.price + wheel.tyre.price}
  end
end

> Wheel.cheapest 
#=> (Cheapest wheel)
```

Update: A scope based solution that works:

```
scope :cheapest, -> {
    includes(:rim, :tyre).joins(:rim, :tyre).order("('rims'.price + 'tyres'.price) ASC")
  }
```